# Icon on AngularJS input type button

Tags: angularjs, button

I can't find any info on this but I'm sure there must be a simple solution. How do you insert an icon in AngularJS input type button. Something like this (although it obviously won't work):

```
<input type="button" ng-click="someAction()"/>
    <i class="fa some-icon"></i>
</input>
```

I know how to do it with normal button elements, but is it possible with AngularJS?

Comment: If you can do with normal button elements, follow the same?

Comment: Try `<button ...><i class=...></i></button>`. Angular doesn't bother about button element, it's very generic in handling elements.

Comment: For the purposes of my project, it would be really great if I could do it using AngularJS. I know I can do `<button ...><i class=...></i></button>`, but I first want to know if there's a purely Angular solution.

Comment: Why do you need to do this w/Angular? You could argue that the Angular way of doing this is not to use Javascript for something you can already do in HTML.

Comment: Angular has a lot of ways to do things that you can do in HTML. It's because of specific needs regarding the model or whatever. In my case the styling and structure appears different when I use a `button` tag and when I use an `input` tag.

Comment: I'm not asking why anyone would want to do this, I'm just asking if it's possible.

Comment: What you seem to be saying is when I try to put an icon inside an `<input>` tag, it doesn't display properly. Angular is not going to change anything about that. In the end the browser will still be rendering HTML/CSS. To me your question sounds like you need to figure out the proper HTML/CSS do this. Trying to put something inside of an `<input>` tag probably isn't going to work in general (even though it's a button in this case). That's why they made the `<button>` tag, so it could contain things.

Comment: Yes, you can't put another element inside the `input` tag. So what about using the `class`, `ng-class`, or maybe even `value` tags?

Comment: @Niel have you found the solution? I am having the similiar scenario

Comment: @Shachi, wow this is an old question...no it's really not possible, the `input` tag doesn't work like that. Use something like input prefixes - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/

Comment: @Niel - yup.. figured out that.. just had to solve some issues in an old project and really not able to remember the js concepts like before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `input` tag doesn't allow tags inside it, but it's easy to make it look like there's an icon in the input. Bootstrap and Angular Material include this in their components.

[Bootstrap Input Group](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/)

[Angular Material input prefixes](https://material.angular.io/components/input/examples)